# Custom font issue in German language in IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, character-encoding, uifont, custom-font

I have been using yorkhandwriting font in my iOS application for different language. Everything is working fine in iOS 6 in german but, in iOS 7 some of the characters are bold. For instance Küche has no problem in case of iOS 6 but, in iOS 7 ü is always bold.

I am using `UILabel` to display.
Following is the code though:

*in localised strings*"Kitchen" = "Küche";

```
[self.lblKitchen setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"yorkhandwriting" size:kSIZE_LABEL_ROOMS]]; 
[self.lblKitchen setText:NSLocalizedString(LABEL_NAME_KITCHEN_HOME_SCREEN,nil)];
```

Font applies well on all alphabets execpt LateX like **ü**, **ó**

Comment: post your relevant code...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Although there is nothing wrong with code when German language selected in the simulator it select string from german localised string file. The only is is that ü is bold in german language. In iOS 6 nothing wrong. Following is the code though:

[self.lblKitchen setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"yorkhandwriting" size:kSIZE_LABEL_ROOMS]];
[self.lblKitchen setText:NSLocalizedString(LABEL_NAME_KITCHEN_HOME_SCREEN,nil)];
#define LABEL_NAME_KITCHEN_HOME_SCREEN @"Kitchen"
"Kitchen" = "Küche";

Comment: Then maybe it's a problem with the font?

Comment: But, it's working perfect on iOS 6. I have tried another font but the issue is still there. Basically, issue is in iOS 7.

Comment: problem with Problems with metal umlauts? It depends on the encoding of the output channel you are using.

Comment: @Mingebag, you made it complicated for me to understand. I have tried in iOS 6 simulator and there is nothing wrong with it. It happens only in case of iOS 7 simulator. I don't know either something has been changed in iOS 7.
I have simply used a custom font which is working perfect on iOS 6 but creating issue on iOS 7.

Comment: Sry. for that ... So what kind of custom font are you using ?

Comment: I have already mentioned that I am using yorkhandwriting (custom font).